# Tensorflow: Undo global average pooling

Tags: python, tensorflow

In Tensorflow I do at the end of my network the following global average pooling:

```
x_ = tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=[1,2])
```

My tensor `x` has the shape `(n, h, w, c)` where `n` is the number of inputs, `w` and `h` correspond to the width and height dimensions, and `c` is the number of channels/filters.

Starting with a tensor `x` of size `(n, h, w, c)` after calling `tf.reduce_mean()` the resulting tensor is of size `(n, c)`.

How can I reverse that process? How can I do the unpooling operation?

**EDIT**

Here is an example which did not work as expected:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

n, c = 1, 2 
h, w = 2, 2

x = tf.ones([n, h, w, c])
y = tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=[1,2], keepdims=True)
z = tf.reshape(y, [n, 1, 1, c])
u = tf.tile(z, [n, h, w, c])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(x)
    print("x", sess.run(x))
    print("\n")
    print(y)
    print("y", sess.run(y))
    print("\n")
    print(z)
    print("z", sess.run(z))
    print("\n")
    print(u)
    print("u", sess.run(u))
```

The output is:

```
Tensor("ones:0", shape=(1, 2, 2, 2), dtype=float32)
x [[[[1. 1.]
   [1. 1.]]

  [[1. 1.]
   [1. 1.]]]]


Tensor("Mean:0", shape=(1, 1, 1, 2), dtype=float32)
y [[[[1. 1.]]]]


Tensor("Reshape:0", shape=(1, 1, 1, 2), dtype=float32)
z [[[[1. 1.]]]]


Tensor("Tile:0", shape=(1, 2, 2, 4), dtype=float32)
u [[[[1. 1. 1. 1.]
   [1. 1. 1. 1.]]

  [[1. 1. 1. 1.]
   [1. 1. 1. 1.]]]]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do the unpooling operation with `tf.reshape` and `tf.tile`.

```
x = tf.random_uniform([n, c])
y = tf.reshape(x, [n, 1, 1, c])
z = tf.tile(y, [1, h, w, 1])
```

Starting with a tensor `x` of size `(n, c)` after calling `tf.reshape` and `tf.tile` the resulting tensor `z` is of size `(n, h, w, c)`.

Comment: When I test your answer, tensor `z` is of size `[n*n, h, w, c*c]`? How can I check, that the unpooling operation worked correctly?

Comment: display tensor shape. print(z.shape)

Comment: I added an example

Comment: sorry, tile was wrond and revise it.